# c# Trying to get byte[] data from an object in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, byte

I have been working on this one for a while, searching forums and Microsoft articles but so far none of what I have found has helps, so I need to ask the experts.

I have been working with a COM reference (third party DLL) in my C# project where one of the outputs gives me some payload data. I am trying to get the byte[] data out into clear text for debugging purposes but here is where I run into problems.

If I watch the Locals during debug, I see that the returned `System.Array` has three Objects. Each object contains a byte[] `(value{byte[253]})`, two bytes and a uint.

If I run the following I can get the objects from the Array, but I am stuck trying to get the byte[] data out of the object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++ )
{
     object myObject = myArray.GetValue(i);
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a friendly heads up, you can format inline code by using backticks. example: `code is formatted inline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do simply the following?

```
byte[] byteArray = myArray.GetValue(i)[0];
```

Your question is a little vague, but I think this will help.

Comment: You'll probably need to cast that: `(byte[])myArray.GetValue(i);` It's hard to say, though. As you pointed out, the question is vague.

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague, I am still in the process of studying programming so I am still a young grasshopper.

If I try either of the above two suggestions I get “InvalidCastException” or “Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object”. 

The byte array is currently inside of an object, so this is where I am trying to get my data from.  Is there anything I should provide to help detail the question?

Comment: You are all my Hero! Thank you so much for your help. Even though none of the answers provided were the exact answer, the suggested cast by @JimMischel led me on the correct searching path to a solution. The DLL included a struct that I needed to cast my object into to get my data. Thank you all again!